# Android make DELETE web service call

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am playing with instagram api endpoints.

Their call sample is:

```
curl -X DELETE https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

I am trying to make the call from my android app like this:

```
URL url = new URL(myBuiltUrl);
HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(false);
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream());
outputStreamWriter.write("access_token=" + token);
outputStreamWriter.flush();
String response = streamToString(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());
```

The error I get while running this code is:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: method does not support a request body: DELETE
```

How can I fix my code to work correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your `access_token` on your `URL`, as you are doing with your **`curl`** command, and getting rid of the `outputStreamWriter` stuff.